# Error in running a bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a bash script `startup_application.sh`
The script is as:

```
#!/bin/sh
vncserver
/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh start
```

Whenever I am trying to run the script I get the following error:

```
 sh '/home/ubuntu/startApplication.sh' start
    : not foundu/startApplication.sh: 2: /home/ubuntu/startApplication.sh: vncserver
    usage: /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh help
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status)
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) apache
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hive_derby
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hive_metastore
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hive_hiveserver2
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hive_webhcat
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hadoop_hdfs
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hadoop_yarn
           /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.7.3-3/ctlscript.sh (start|stop|restart|status) hadoop_timelineserver

    help       - this screen
    start      - start the service(s)
    stop       - stop  the service(s)
    restart    - restart or start the service(s)
    status     - show the status of the service(s)
```

What I need to do inorder to resolve this issue. Kindly suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: Install vncserver

Comment: @Alfe It is already there I am trying to call it or initiate it using bash script.

Comment: You could have a problem with differing environments.  Try using the complete path to the vncserver (enter `type vncserver` to see it).

Comment: @Alfe Please let me tell you that the vncserver is not issue. The next line initiating Hadoop is. I have written `vncserver` directly in the bash file and it ran perfectly.